# Gaussian kernel density smoothing for pandas.DataFrame.resample?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, smoothing, kernel-density

I am using `pandas.DataFrame.resample` to resample random events to 1 hour intervals and am seeing very stochastic results that don't seem to go away if I increase the interval to 2 or 4 hours.  It makes me wonder whether Pandas has any type of method for generating a smoothed density kernel like a Gaussian kernel density method with an adjustable bandwidth to control smoothing.  I'm not seeing anything in the documentation, but thought I would post here before posting on the developer list server since that is their preference.  Scikit-Learn has [precisely the Gaussian kernel density function that I want](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html), so I will try to make use of it, but it would be a fantastic addition to Pandas.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
hourly[0][344:468].plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Pandas has the ability to apply an aggregation over a rolling window.  The `win_type` parameter controls the window's shape.  The `center` parameter can be set in order for the labels to be set at the center of the window, instead of the right edge.  To do Gaussian smoothing:

```
hrly = pd.Series(hourly[0][344:468])
smooth = hrly.rolling(window=5, win_type='gaussian', center=True).mean(std=0.5)
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling

Answer (score 3):

I have now found that this is option is available in `pandas.stats.moments.ewma` and it works quite nicely.  Here are the results:

```
from pandas.stats.moments import ewma

hourly[0][344:468].plot(style='b')
ewma(hourly[0][344:468], span=35).plot(style='k')
```

[image]

Comment: Exponential weighted moving average is a real-time (only backward-looking) filter, and isn't the same as a Gaussian kernel, which is imaginary-time (looks forward and backward).